# How to make a MASM32 project run during boot up?

Tags: assembly, bootstrapping

We all know that assembly language is almost the closest we can get to machine code.

But how can I configure the BIOS so that it gets run during bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think you need to configure the BIOS.  You need to either replace (or augment) the boot loader, or hook in downstream from it.  Not for the faint-hearted.  If you want it to execute earlier than that, you have to replace the BIOS code, which means burning a new PROM.  http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up

Comment: Is there a hello world demo for this?

Comment: There's a hello world demo at this answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267988/how-to-write-execute-pure-machine-code-manually/5268120#5268120

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You write the code onto a disk as a boot loader and then the BIOS will launch it normally.  Don't do it to a disk that has anything on it that you care about (like a working OS).  It's not hard to do, but you do have the potential to totally destroy any data on the machine you do this to, so use caution.