# Visual C++ compile flat binary

Tags: c++, compilation

Is it possible to compile a completely flat binary file with no structure in VC++? And if so how?

Comment: Please explain by what you mean by flat - binaries do not have a shape

Comment: Define your terms. What is the "flat binary file" and what does it mean to "compile it"?

Comment: Compile it?  You mean include it in the resulting exe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write/execute PURE machine code manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267988/how-to-write-execute-pure-machine-code-manually)

Comment: From wikipedia: `If a binary file does not contain any headers, it may be called a flat binary file.`

Comment: @JesseGood Meaning less words - what are `headers`

Comment: Yes no headers , I am developing an OS and would like to use C++

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

VisualC++ is a C++ compiler; it takes C++ source code and produces object files. If you want something else, use a different tool.