# Compile code to raw binary

Tags: gcc, command-line, machine-code, objcopy

I'm trying to compile my code into raw binary and as suggested by other SO posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647405/363949) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615546/363949)) I tried objdump:

```
$ gcc -c foo.c
$ objcopy -O binary foo.o foo.bin
```

Then I tried to make sure if this is valid:

```
$ objdump -d foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   b:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
   f:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  14:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  19:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1e <main+0x1e>
  1e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  23:   c9                      leaveq 
  24:   c3                      ret

$ hexdump -C foo.bin

00000000  14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 7a 52 00 01 78 10 01  |.........zR..x..|
00000010  1b 0c 07 08 90 01 00 00  1c 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 25 00 00 00  00 41 0e 10 86 02 43 0d  |....%....A....C.|
00000030  06 60 0c 07 08 00 00 00                           |.`......|
00000038
```

Evidently something is wrong. I checked this with the results of a gcc cross-compilation, with much the same obviously incorrect results.

Comment: Shouldn't you link before you convert to bin?

Comment: In any case, one of the comments for one of the answers you linked to suggests using `-j .text` as an argument to `objcopy`.

Comment: Try `objcopy -j text -O binary`.

Comment: @Michael Adding `-j .text` seems to be working fine. Thank you. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get gcc to output raw binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `-j .text` to `objcopy`.